# How big my sprites should be in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, pixel

I'm making a 2D retro-style pixel game and I'd like to know how big my sprites should be.

I'm not talking about the size of my image files (which I decided to use a 32x32-based artstyle), but the actual size of them once they are in Unity.

Should I keep a 1:1 scale and import all of my usually 32x32 sprites into Unity? Is there a special scale up or down process I need to do before or after import them?

I'm saying this because when I'm working with HUD elements, they are drastically really big compared to my tiny sprites, so I'm worried if this could affect implementing something like RigidBody or collisions,  and I should indeed scale up my sprites, or if this is normal and I'm being paranoic.

I'll append an image showing my concern.

BTW, the game looks so far as I wanted to, and it's working well, but right now it's more like a proto, so I'd like to resolve this doubt before continuing. Also, I test this usually in a 1920x1080 resolution, so maybe that's why the HUD looks so big.

Thanks!

[image: gif proportions in game]

Comment: While in the Unity editor, UI canvases usually appear quite huge compared to the rest of the scene. The editor visualizes them with one unit for one pixel, which is usually a much much bigger scale than you would use in most games. Don't let that confuse you.

Comment: The mismatch you're describing is just because screenspace UI, by default, is expressed in pixel coordinates to help make it easy to transfer 2D mock-ups into working game interfaces. Worldspace elements like your gameplay are expressed in world units, which is a size that's completely up to you. We usually choose to think of this unit as 1m, or the size of our main building block (eg. tile) or common element like a character, to make the size of our world intuitive to reason about and not coupled to any one specific display resolution.

Comment: thanks @Philipp, as you said yeah that confused me, but after searching about it I found the same you just said so I'll continue with that in mind.

Comment: @DMGregory I'll try to follow what you mentioned (the 1 unit to 1m). Also, the linked question helps me understand this more, thanks!